# what is RELY constraint in hive external tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, constraints, external-tables

[managed table vs external table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Managed+vs.+External+Tables)

in above link they mentioned

**"Only the RELY constraint is allowed on external tables."**

But no info that what is RELY constraint. Can somebody help me to understand what is Only the "RELY constraint". thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

CBO is expected to take into account constraint, trust it if it is defined with RELY option. CBO may produce better plan and eliminate unnecessary joins.
See also Jira [HIVE-13350](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13350)